# Efficient PDF Handling in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework

I'm looking to this fantastic community to point me in the right direction. I am building an application that will in part work with PDF files.

Essentially I will have one or more large PDF files that need to be split into smaller PDF files. Right now we are using PHP and the Zend Framework.

The Zend Framework does support this but I've found it to be rather slow when working with larger PDF files. Is there a command line tool, or a library that is faster / more efficient that any of you know about?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user mpdf.

http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

I have used this in more than 5 projects and its doing great.

Comment: Does this allow for extracting pages from an existing PDF?

Comment: there is a feature of overlay one pdf to another pdf and hence that feature can be used.                                                             http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=349                                              http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=350

Comment: Hmm that's not quite what I meant but I see how it can be used that way. Will have to give it a try :)